# Which explicit expressions for $\Bbb E [ f(Z\sqrt{t} +x)]=\int_{\Bbb R} f(u \sqrt{t} + x) e^{-u^2 /2} du$ are known, where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: reference-request, normal-distribution, closed-form

I would like to collect a list of known explicit expression of the form
$$h(x,t) = \Bbb E [ f(Z\sqrt{t} +x)],$$
where $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb [0,\infty )$ is a measurable, non-negative function and $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, this means $Z$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Alternatively, the quantity above can be written as
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u \sqrt{t} + x) (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-u^2 /2} du = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(u \sqrt{t} + x) \phi (u) du,$$
where $\phi(u) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} e^{-u^2 /2}$. Further define $\Phi (z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \phi(u)du$.

By "explicitely" I mean that the expression $h(x,t)=0$ has a chance to be solved for the variable $x$ in dependence of $t$ in an explicit way.

There are of course some trivial/known examples ([normal distribution german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalverteilung#Momenterzeugende_Funktion)):

- $f(u) = 1$
- $f(u) = u^{n}$, then $h(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}(2k-1)!!t^k x^{n-2k}$
- $f(u) =  e^{\lambda u}$, then $h(x,t) = e^{\lambda x + \frac{t\lambda^2}{2}}$

Of special interest for me are functions $f$, which are symmetric, i.e. $f(u)=f(-u)$,

- $f(u) = \vert u\vert$, then $h(x,t) = \sqrt{t \frac{2}{\pi}} e^{-x/2t} + x(1 - 2\Phi (-x /\sqrt{t}))$ ([folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution))
- $f(u) = \phi(u) $, then $h(x,t)=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{t}{t+1}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2t(t+1)} - \frac{x^2}{2t}}$ (Example 6, Hans Rudolf Lerche, Boundary Crossing of Brownian Motion)

or functions, which vanish for $u < 0$, i.e. $f(u) = 0$ for $u<0$,

- $f(u) = 1_{[0,\infty )}(u)$, then $h(x,t) = 1 - \Phi (x/\sqrt{t})$

Comment: This question seems far too broad, as we have the equivalent $\int_{\Bbb R}f(s)e^{as^2-2as}\,ds$ for some constant $a$ and we can choose any function $g(s)$ which has a closed-form integral and take $f(s)=g(s)e^{2as-as^2}$.

Comment: I know what you mean. But the goal is that $f$ should not depend on $x$.